# Column formula in sharepoint list

Tags: infopath, column, form

I have made a list with InfoPath in SharePoint. All the questions are either "accepted" or "notaccepted" (radiobuttons) and I want to make a new column (in SharePoint). If someone choose "accepted", the value it gives to the list is 1, and "Notaccepted" is 2.

I want to create a new column which looks at all the columns in the list (let's say for easy sake A, B & C) and when they are all at value 1, the new column gets the value accepted, and when only 1 question is answered with "Notaccepted" ( so only one,or more, value 2) it has to say "Notaccepted".

So if

```
A=1
B=1
C= 1
```

It should return "Accepted",

When it is

```
A=1
B=2
C=1
```

it should give "Notaccepted"

If

```
A=2
B=2
C=1
```

it should still say "Not accepted"

Can anyone help me out with this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided Columns A,B,C have either a 1 or 2 value;

```
=IF( INT(A)+INT(B)+INT(C) = 3  ,  "Accepted" , "Not Accepted" )
```

checks if ALL 3 columns have a value of 1

```
=IF( MIN( INT(A) , INT(B) , INT(C) ) = 0 , "One of the columns is 0" ,"None of the colums are 0" )
```

Checks if either one of ABC is 0

```
=IF( MAX( INT(A) , INT(B) , INT(C) ) = 2 , "One of the columns is 2" ,"None of the colums are 2" )
```

Checks if either of the columns is 2

combined: answers are not accepted when 0 or 2 are given as any answer in A,B,C

```
=IF( 
    OR( 
        MIN( INT(A) , INT(B) , INT(C) ) = 0 
        , 
        MAX( INT(A) , INT(B) , INT(C) ) = 2
      )
    ,  "Not Accepted"
    , "Accepted" 
)
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks! If they can have a value 0(if they dont choose either one of the answers), value 1(accepted) and value 2 (Not Accepted), is that possible aswell :O? 
Thanks for your respondse btw! ^^

Comment: what you want if their is value 0?